# Convert one number spectrum into another

Tags: algorithm, math

I'm trying to come up with a formular which converts one number spectrum into another.
For example:

`0 - 800` to `-1 - 1`

Where `0 = -1`, `200 = -0.5`, `400 = 0`, `600 = 0.5`, `800 = 1`, and so on.

The difficult part for me seems to be the negative range.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your ranges are `a0, a1` and `b0, b1`, then you want `x` to go to

```
((x-a0)/(a1-a0)) * (b1-b0) + b0
```

Basically, `(x-a0)` is how far over you are from the lower side of the first range, and `(x-a0)/(a1-a0)` divides by the width of the range so the number is now normalized to `[0, 1]`.  After that, we multiply by `(b1-b0)` to expand the range to the new scale, and add `b0` to shift it over.

For example:

```
>>> a0, a1 = 0.0, 800.0
>>> b0, b1 = -1.0, 1.0
>>> 
>>> x = 400 # should go to 0
>>> x-a0
400.0
>>> (x-a0)/(a1-a0)
0.5
>>> (x-a0)/(a1-a0) * (b1-b0)
1.0
>>> (x-a0)/(a1-a0) * (b1-b0) + b0
0.0
>>> x = 0 # should go to -1
>>> (x-a0)/(a1-a0) * (b1-b0) + b0
-1.0
>>> x = 800 # should go to 1
>>> (x-a0)/(a1-a0) * (b1-b0) + b0
1.0
```