# Calculating radial velocity from an inverse linear scale

Tags: algorithm, math, logic

I have a user input that can have an integer value of 1 through 50.
i have, let's imagine, a needle that turns, like it was a clock.
The speed of that turn is determined by the delta in radians it moves every frame.
So, if i have a speed of PI/2, the needle turns a half circle every frame.
I have come to the conclusion that the possible speed, should be between PI/8 (the fastest) and PI/256 (the slowest).

I am trying to build an algorithm that will translate the user input of 1 (the slowest) and 50 (the fastest) into PI/256 and PI/8 (the max value 50 is arbitrary, can be something else); obviously the numbers between should be in reverse correspondence.

what i need would be a formula like:

```
delta = userInput * (.............)
```

I'have been trying for hours, if someone could help me out would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Can you follow the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12413829/convert-one-number-spectrum-into-another)?

Comment: @DSM  I read it and it seems to make sense, even though i'm not fit to try it right now. The problem I see is that there is no inverse correlation, the scales grow in the same direction; and this is the biggest problem i have

Comment: That's not actually a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12413829/convert-one-number-spectrum-into-another) for a more detailed explanation of why this works.)

This was just slightly too long for a comment.  Whether the two scales agree in direction doesn't matter, although yours *do*: you said `1` (the slowest) corresponds to `pi/256` (the slowest), and `50` (the fastest) corresponds to `pi/8` (the fastest).  `1 < 50`, and `pi/256 < pi/8`.

So if that's the right ordering:

```
>>> a0, a1 = 1., 50.
>>> b0, b1 = pi/256, pi/8
>>> def rescale(x): 
...     return ((x-a0)/(a1-a0)) * (b1-b0) + b0
... 
>>> rescale(1)
0.01227184630308513
>>> rescale(1) == pi/256
True
>>> 
>>> rescale(50)
0.39269908169872414
>>> rescale(50) == pi/8
True
```

with `25` somewhere close to the middle:

```
>>> rescale(25)
0.198603553435643
```

If you want `1` to correspond to the fastest speed instead, then simply flip `b0` and `b1`:

```
>>> a0, a1 = 1., 50.
>>> b0, b1 = pi/8, pi/256
>>> def rescale(x): 
...     return ((x-a0)/(a1-a0)) * (b1-b0) + b0
... 
>>> rescale(1)
0.39269908169872414
>>> rescale(50)
0.012271846303085143
```

The formula continues to apply.

Comment: lol, you're right about the inversion, i am just tired. I will try this out tomorrow, and accept the answer then. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Solve the line equation: y = m * x + b. I.e., plug in your two points to get two equations with m and b as unknowns, then solve for m and b.

Comment: I assume y is the result i'm looking for; i have no idea what m, x, b, l and e stand for. can you please explain better?

Comment: Think of x as the user input and y as the output.